# Myo armband gestures in MATLAB (Unable to compile the .m or .mex file)

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, myo

I need some help to make a myo-mex file to work. I don't know how to change the compiler options so that the mingw supports ISO c++ 2011. The github repository where the code is can be found here: https://github.com/mark-toma/MyoMex. 
The error message Im getting look like the following:

```
Error using build_myo_mex (line 61)
In file included from C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/MW_MinGW_4_9/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/array:35:0,
             from C:\MyoMex-master\MyoMex\myo_mex\myo_class.hpp:16,
             from C:\MyoMex-master\MyoMex\myo_mex\myo_mex.cpp:14:
C:/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2015b/MW_MinGW_4_9/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-  mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
```

Im a bit clueless of this error, but I hope someone will be able to help since Im not the best at using MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Its mentioned right in the error message

> This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the
>   `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` compiler options.

Use:

`-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

Comment: That is the problem how do i change the compiler options to -std=c++11?

Comment: @MartinJensen You'll have to update an xml or .sh file for the mex build
under `\bin\win64\mexopts` . Update the compiler flag to include `-std=c++11` . Sorry I don't have access to any system that has matlab installed.